# Android - How to hide the Menu Button in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to hide the menu button in the action bar, how to hide it in action bar on Android? My minSdkVersion is 7, and I'm using support-v7-appcompat.

Comment: Do you mean the overflow menu button (the one with the 3 dots)?

Comment: Refer to @CommonsWare answer. And please **accept** it. I couldn't be more concise and perfectly descriptive at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the action bar overflow (three-dots affordance), you "hide it" by not having anything in the overflow. That affordance will only appear if something appears in the overflow, either because you put it in the overflow (`app:showAsAction="never"` and `android:showAsAction="never"`), or there was insufficient room in the action bar for everything else you wanted.